# Magento- add submit button to sales order grid

Tags: php, magento, model-view-controller

I am using Magento to build a custom extension.
I have added a few new fields to the sales order tables and want to add a new submit button next to each order in the sales order grid in the admin section.

Now, I think I've found a few tutorials that show me how add extra fields to the admin page, but how would I intercept the submit button getting clicked?

Do I create my own event and subscribe to this event, using a controller to process my logic?

Answer (score 0):

What is your desired end result?  What you would want to do is override the the controller that is being posted to currently.  There are tutorials out there for overriding controllers: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller

There is no need to create your own event, just override the controller and use add the extra logic needed to handle your new fields.  Hope this helps.